# match across two columns to define a numeric value

Tags: r, match

Taking some basic data

```
Aa <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5)
Bb <- c(3,6,1,1,2,1,4)
Cc <- 1:length(Aa)
Dd <- sample(1:10,7)
df <- data.frame(Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd)
colnames(df)[1] <- "ID"
colnames(df)[2] <- "Type"
colnames(df)[3] <- "PNR"
colnames(df)[4] <- "height"


Dd <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5)
Ee <- c(3,3,3,6,1,1,1,4)
Ff <- c(1,2,3,3,1,3,2,2)
df2 <- data.frame(Dd,Ee,Ff)
colnames(df2)[1] <- "ID"
colnames(df2)[2] <- "Type"
colnames(df2)[3] <- "Class"
```

I want to create `df2$PNR` which calls upon the values from `df$PNR` where `ID` and `Type` are identical.

I have used the code:

```
df2$PNR <- df$PNR[match(df2$ID==df$ID & df2$Type==df$Type)]
```

Any guidence would be appreciated to output this

```
df2
#  ID Type Class PNR
#1  1    3     1   1
#2  1    3     2   1
#3  1    3     3   1
#4  1    6     3   2
#5  3    1     1   4
#6  3    1     3   4
#7  4    1     2   6
#8  5    4     2   7
```

A solution has been suggested to `merge`, but I do not want to merge all the data (ie. i dont want `$height` in `df2`)

Comment: Apparently you want to `merge`.

Comment: @Roland, in this simple example yes merge works. But I have more complex data.frames with unequal variables names in df and df2 - thus I just want to match PNR based on the constraints. So can another solution be found without merge?

Comment: I don't see why `merge` shouldn't work in that case. Have you studied `help("merge")`?

Comment: question updated, in the output I dont want all the variables from df merged into df2

Comment: Simply subset `df` to the columns you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `merge(df2, df, by=c("ID","Type"))`, but first correct to `Cc <- 1:length(Aa)`

If you want to exclude variables you can do it before the "merge" like : `df$height = NULL` or do it after the join :

```
result = merge(df2, df, by=c("ID","Type"))
result$height=NULL
result
```

Comment: so I updated the question, now we dont want to include height in our second data.frame. I have used the following syntax `df3 <- merge(df2, df, by=c("ID","Type"), all.x=TRUE, all.y = FALSE)` but its not quiet right